# How can I get the last tag inner HTML?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-table

I want to get the last item which the last item in the specific tags,

I mean ;

```
     <tr>
        <td><b>my name</b></td>
        <td><spec id="nm" nm="eg">Example Name</spec>   
        </td>
    </tr>
    ....

 <tr>
    <td><b>samp2</b></td>
    <td title="samp2"><div>Example 2</div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

I want to reach `"Example Name"` I want to write a dynamic program? How can I do that?

(you can see the the last tag is `"spec"` maybe the other scenerio the last tag is `sam` how can I find last tag inner html? second sample I want to get `Example 2`)

### updated sample

if I has this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><div>2</div></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><span>3</span></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I need the output should be:

### 2 and 3

because they are the last tags inner html under `tr` tag.

(I want to last tag under tr tag , but if it has child element I want to its inner html)

thanks in advance?

Comment: Parse the text for `<tr>`, parse the text for `<td>`, obtain last `<td>`-Element.

Comment: can you post your full `<table>` html? Does every `<tr>` have the same content as this one?

Comment: I edit my question , every tr has td but it td , there could be diffirent tags , I want to last tag inner html

Comment: @verisimilitude I update my question again

Comment: You clearly don't want the "last" tag, because that would be _only_ the `<span>3</span>` and you say you want both the 2 and the 3, so you need to better explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @StephenP I want to last tag under tr tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) html parser to do it, you can use css or jquery like selector to find element

```
    String html = "<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    System.out.println(doc);
    Elements elements = doc.select("tr td:last-child");
    for(Element element: elements) {
        System.out.println(element.html());
    }
```

**output**

```
2
4
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try with a regex like :

`/<spec[^>]*>(.*?)<\/spec>/`

i think it is not efficient but you can try, check the regex for a better performance

`/<td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td><\/tr>/`

this is an approximation. would fail the subject of child. You can use this result to remove span, div etc.

`/<(.*?)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/(.*?)>/`

Comment: but the spec is not always the tag which I want to search, it will change, sometimes divsometimes span